# Geometric series of binary relation

Tags: symmetric-matrices, spectral-graph-theory

Let $\rho\subset X\times X$ be a symmetric binary relation on a finite set $X$. Let $\overline{\rho}\subset X\times X$ be its transitive closure :
$$
\overline{\rho}=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty \rho^{\circ i}.
$$
If we choose a labeling $\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\xrightarrow\sim X$ of the elements of $X$ and consider the associated matrix $\overline{M}=(\overline{m}_{ij})$ whose entries are in $\{0,1\}$ and satisfy
$$
\overline{m}_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }(\sigma(i),\sigma(j))\in\overline{\rho},\\
0 & \text{if }(\sigma(i),\sigma(j))\notin\overline{\rho}
\end{cases}
$$
then we get that if $L$ is the cardinality of the largest equivalence class in $\overline{\rho}$, and there are $c$ such equivalence classes, then
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\overline{M}^k)\simeq cL^{k+1}$$

> **Question.** Is there a procedure to extract $c$ and $L$ straight from $\rho$ and its associated symmetric matrix ?